# meta stackoverflow showing This question body does not meet our quality standards

Tags: discussion, support

why meta stackoverflow showing This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

[image]

Comment: Weird, as far as I know those filters are turned off on Meta. What did you try to post exactly?

Comment: i have just posted 'how can i get or earn **code editor** on _stackoverflow_.

Comment: Anyway the error is very clear. For one, in English, when referencing yourself it's "I", not "i". Plus no need for a quote in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks shadow its working.

Comment: I see you deleted it eventually. If you can explain what you mean by "get code editor" maybe I can still understand and help you after all.

Comment: Thanks shadow but i don't know how to explain, may be it was wrong question i am asking about.
thanks a lot to still supporting me :)